# javascript - stop browser highlighting images

Tags: javascript, highlighting

I have made a script that allows users to drag images around. Unfortunatly though most browsers higlight the image blue. Is there a way to disable this behaviour in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return false from your mousedown/mousemove handler to prevent default browser actions (default action is the select the underlying element on mousedrag).

**EDIT**

What I meant was this:

```
document.onmousemove = function() {
    // Do your stuff

    return false;
}
```

You might have different looking functions, but in the end, put `return false`.

Comment: @Mark - so use it, and at the end of it, return `false`.

Comment: @Mark, edit your question and post the code you have so far, it's hard to help you if I have to guess what's wrong.